# Total Count(customer_ids) with below requirement

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to **hive** and **sql**.

**Input:**

```
customer_id   
201301        
201302        
201303        
201301
201301
```

I want output as total customer ids.

```
Total count
   5
```

I am trying: `sum(count(customer_id)) as count_column group by customer_id`.

I am my query i dont use customer id column. I use only count as column

Please let me know if it works

Comment: What is the database and table are you referring in the query? Please provide the complete query as you are using.

Comment: database and table name, which store this data in hive?

Comment: Hi abhishek thanks for the quick reply-Hadoop hive is my data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select COUNT(customer_ID) as TotalCount from table_name
```

Comment: so need of need of adding sum function ?

Comment: Sorry but count(customer_id) is giving total count for each customer_id row by row .But my requirement  is to sum(all customer ids) with no groupby.